# Scheme Tail Recursion (BitsOn count)

Tags: recursion, scheme, tail-recursion, bit

I need some help to implement a function that receives a number and returns the number of bits that would have been required to be “on” in order to represent the input number in binary base.
For example, the number 5 is represented as 101 in binary and therefore requires two bits to be “on”.

Example:
(numOfBitsOn 5) will return 2 because 5 in binary is 101
(numOfBitsOn 101) will return 4 because 101 in binary is 1100101

- The function must be written as tail recursion.

This is m first time learning Scheme. Up to now this is all I wrote:

```
(define (numOfBitsOn number)
  (define (numOfBitsOn-2 number acc)
    (cond ((eq? number 0)acc)
          (not(eq? (modulo number 2)0) (+ acc 1))
          (numOfBitsOn-2 (/ number 2) acc))))
```

And it gives me that:

```
begin (possibly implicit): no expression after a sequence of internal definitions in: (begin (define (numofbitson-2 number acc) (cond ((eq? number 0) acc) (not (eq? (modulo number 2) 0) (+ acc 1)) (numofbitson-2 (number) acc))))
```

I'm sure it doesn't even close to the solution =\

Can you help me please?
Thanks!

Comment: Hint: you define `numOfBitsOn-2`, but you never actually call it from outside of its own definition. Also, just as a side note, Scheme naming conventions specify that elements of names should be separated by hyphens, not camel case, so your function should be called `num-of-bits-on`.

Comment: What do you mean by "you never actually call it from outside of its own definition"? Where should I call it (I taught the last line suppose to do this) ?

Comment: Yes, you need to call `numOfBitsOn-2` from inside `numOfBitsOn` but outside `numOfBitsOn-2` to "kick off" the recursion. Consider a function `(define (f) (f))`. Not a very useful function because all it does is call itself forever. However, simply *defining* that function does nothing at all! You have to call `(f)` first to get stuck in the endless loop.

Comment: I'm not sure I I got what you meant man and I'm doesn't know the syntax very well. Can you please try to write it down? Am I in the right way here?

Comment: @user5500724 Alexis's comments are all correct, but, I've posted a wholly new answer just for reference. You should still follow her advice if you want to use your solution approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (slow-popcount n)
  (do ((n n (quotient n 2))
       (count 0 (+ count (modulo n 2))))
      ((zero? n) count)))
```